Is there a software for several Ubuntu computers where I can log the cpu, memory and gpu usage over time?
I am looking for an open-source and simple solution. It also can be a script.
I want to get an overview over the team, if I need to upgrade hardware.
Honestly, I tried to google but I havn't found something useful. If I can get some useful key words to search, I would be happy.
I made another post in softwarerecs

This belongs on software recommendations Stack Exchange.

@security_paranoid I am not sure. I would alos be happy for a script (code),  which connects to each computer and logs it every 2 hours.

Well I’d recommend something like Netdata.

this is not open-source

Please do not crosspost. See Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?
